# How to determine the largest digit in 5 digit integer?

Tags: java

How can I locate where among the 5 digit integer is the largest? it always print `Rightmost` even if the largest number is not the last digit.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

int num = in.nextInt();
int digit = 0, lastdigit = 0, middledigit = 0, firstdigit = 0; 

while(num > 0) {

 digit = num % 10;

 if(digit > lastdigit) {
  lastdigit = digit;
  System.out.println("Rightmost");
  return;
 }
 if(digit > middledigit) {
  middledigit = digit;
  System.out.println("Middle");
  return;
 }
 if(digit > firstdigit) {
  firstdigit = digit;
  System.out.println("Leftmost");
  return;
 } else {
    System.out.println("Unknown");
   }

num /= 10;

}
```

***Input:*** `14632`

***Output:*** `Rightmost`

***Expected output:*** `Middle`

and if none of the above is corret it will print *Unknown*.

***Input:*** `77787`

***Output:*** `Unknown`

Comment: what do you think this does? if(digit > lastdigit) { if digit > 0 => rightmost

Comment: I actualy dont know. Im new in this programming. @Stultuske

Comment: The first if-statement will always be true for a non-zero digit. Then it does its included code and returns so nothing else is done.

Comment: I get that `11111` is `Unknown`, that `91111` is `Leftmost`, that `11911` is `Middle`, and that `11119` is `Rightmost`, but what do you call `19111` and `11191`?

Comment: the first two and the last two digit are leftmost and rightmost. @Andreas

Comment: `91111` is leftmost, but the dictionary says that "leftmost" means "farthest to the left", and I certainly wouldn't say that `19111` has the 9 **farthest** to the left.

Comment: Sorry, I mean it should print unknown.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array with the 5 digits, obtain the maximum, and then:

Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(maximum)

You can also use:

```
   int[] my_array={1,4,6,3,2};
   int index_of_largest=0;
   int maximum=array[0];    
   for(int i=1;i<array.length;i++){
        if(my_array[i]>maximum){
            index_of_largest =i;
            maximum=array[i];
        }
   }
```

Comment: This is good advice. I think we can assume there are no duplicate digits.

Comment: @Bohemian since he gave 77787 as an example of input, I think we can assume there are :)

Comment: @Stultuske touché. It’s unclear, but it seems that right most is the preferential result. If so, the index won’t work if the right most is duplicated. You could reverse the array then reverse the index, but that’s getting messy. This answer is on the right track though: *first* find the max, *then* figure out where it lies.

Comment: @Bohemian the code would imply that, but according to the OP's explanation, that input should result in 'unknown'

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't work as intended because `lastdigit` is 0, and the program will return terminating the while loop as soon as it goes to the line `return;` in `if(digit > lastdigit)`, in case the digit you check is greater than 0. This prevents your while loop from proceedings to the other digits to find the correct answer.

Also, the current if-statements in your while loop can't determine which digit it's checking right now. You might want to use a for loop instead or define a counter variable before your while loop.